# Tokeninfo endpoint gives 400 Invalid Value for newly refreshed token

Tags: google-oauth

Since last week, two of our users have been unable to grant us working Google OAuth2 tokens. The refresh tokens we obtain for these users can be exchanged for new access tokens, but the new tokens are also invalid.

We use the [OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer) flow. For both users, the OAuth2 `authentication_code` request succeeds and we obtain access and refresh tokens. But requests made to authorized APIs using the granted access tokens fail with 401 statuses, and hitting `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=XXXXX` fails with a 400 status and `{ error_description: "Invalid Value" }` in the body.

**The strange thing is, the refresh tokens we get for these users appear to be valid, and we can `POST` them to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token` to obtain new access tokens. The new tokens, however, exhibit the same behavior as the old ones.**

The problem persists for these two users even if they revoke our access and go back through the OAuth process, in which case the tokens exhibit the same strange behavior.

We've tried refreshing these and other users' tokens repeatedly and the access tokens returned for the affected users are consistently treated as invalid while tokens for other users work normally. Other users who revoke access and reauthorize obtain working tokens.

The scopes granted for all users are `https://mail.google.com/`, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile`, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email` and `https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/`.

I found a thread on the [old Groups list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/oauth2-dev/tokeninfo/oauth2-dev/7cFAlDgkSpQ/mQrlxHuMCvQJ) that describes something similar, but there's no resolution posted there, and it's been long enough that I suspect the present issue has a different root cause.

Comment: could it be this "We are experiencing an issue with App Engine applications accessing Google APIs beginning at Monday, 2015-12-08 22:00 US/Pacific. Affected APIs may return a "401 Invalid Credentials" error message. For everyone who is affected, we apologize for any inconvenience you may be experiencing. We will provide an update by 2015-12-09 03:30 US/Pacific with current details."

Comment: Definitely possible. We're not on App Engine and we've been seeing this since at least the 5th, but possible it's the same root cause.

Comment: The App Engine issue @pinoyyid mentioned was marked resolved yesterday and we're now able to refresh the affected users' tokens and obtain working tokens. Looks like it was the same underlying issue.